# Hardware/Software/Firmware suggestions for hooking up 2 monitors on XPS15 7590 running Ubuntu 20.04

Tags: nvidia, 20.04, multiple-monitors, xorg, xps

I have an XPS15 7590 running 20.04. I want to get 2 more external monitors for my laptop because with 2TB of storage and 64GB of RAM, I shouldn't have a problem using this beast laptop with 2 external displays. I will be buying benq 4k 60Hz and an Acer 144hz FHD for my monitors.

How do I connect these 2 monitors to my laptop? Do I need to use a docking station? If so, what sort of docking station would you recommend?

As far as my xorg.conf files or anything else goe, what sort of changes do I need to make?

Of course I might run into problems even after "figuring everything out" but I at least want to have a decent road map before I make any sort of purchase. I got inspired by my buddy's setup here:[image]

But he is running windows so me setting it up will be different than his.

Comment: Beware the small portable docks from Dell - despite appearances they only support one monitor. You need one of the more expensive desktop brick-like docking stations. I'm on 18.04 kubuntu on a XPS 13 with a 4k mirror of the laptop screen and a second portrait-orientation monitor. The only niggle is that I have to unplug the dock before closing the laptop lid to suspend, and open the lid to wake up again before plugging the dock back in. But it's no biggie - just a single USB-C cable. But I did have to get to grips with the xrandr command but that might have changed in 20.04.

Comment: B.Tanner. Could you give me more info on your setup? We can chat if you want.